# Adding Row Values when there are no results - MySQL

Tags: mysql, rows

Problem Statement: I need my result set to include records that would not naturally return because they are NULL.

I'm going to put some simplified code here since my code seems to be too long.

Table `Scores` has `Company_type`, `Company`, `Score`, `Project_ID`

```
Select Score, Count(Project_ID)
    FROM Scores
    WHERE company_type= :company_type
    GROUP BY Score
```

Results in the following:

```
Score   Projects
5       95
4       94
3       215
2       51
1       155
```

Everything is working fine until I apply a condition to company_type that does not include results in one of the 5 score categories.  When this happens, I don't have 5 rows in my result set any more.

It displays like this:

```
Score   Projects
5       5
3       6
1       3
```

I'd like it to display like this:

```
Score   Projects
5       5
4       0
3       6
2       0
1       3
```

I need the results to always display 5 rows. (Scores = 1-5)

---

I tried one of the approaches below by Spencer7593.  My simplified query now looks like this:

SELECT i.score AS `Score`, IFNULL(count(*), 0) AS `Projects`
  FROM (SELECT 5 AS score
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 4
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1) i
       LEFT JOIN Scores ON Scores.score = i.score
GROUP BY Score
ORDER BY i.score DESC

And gives the following results, which is accurate except that the rows with 1 in Projects should actually be 0 because they are derived by the "i".  There are no projects with a score of 5 or 2.

```
Score   Projects
5       1
4       5
3       6
2       1
1       3
```

---

Solved!  I just needed to adjust my count to specifically look at the project count - count(project) rather than count(*).  This returned the expected results.

Comment: What is the condition you are applying to the data?

Comment: Please show your query and your table structure.  You most likely need to use an `outer join`.

Comment: Sorry - new to this having trouble with it not allowing me to paste in my sql even when I do a ctrl-K to paste.

Comment: Which OS are you in? ctrl-c(Windows), cmd-c(MAC) for paste

Comment: windows - I was using ctrl K to do code block and then ctrl c to paste - but was receiving errors that it was formatted wrong.

Comment: I take a guess and suggest you have a look at this: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: I'm not sure why this question needed to be closed and downvoted. Okay,  it's not an *outstanding* question, and could maybe use improvement, but its answerable, and decent enough to be salvageable. +10 from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always want your query to return 5 rows, with `Score` values of 5,4,3,2,1... you'll need a rowsource that supplies those `Score` values.

One approach would be to use a simple query to return those fixed values, e.g.

```
 SELECT 5 AS score
 UNION ALL SELECT 4
 UNION ALL SELECT 3
 UNION ALL SELECT 2
 UNION ALL SELECT 1
```

Then use that query as inline view, and do an outer join operation to the results from your current query

```
 SELECT i.score                AS `Score`
      , IFNULL(q.projects,0)   AS `Projects`
   FROM ( SELECT 5 AS score
          UNION ALL SELECT 4
          UNION ALL SELECT 3
          UNION ALL SELECT 2
          UNION ALL SELECT 1
        ) i
   LEFT
   JOIN (
          -- the current query with "missing" Score rows goes here
          -- for completeness of this example, without the query 
          -- we emulate that result with a different query
          SELECT 5 AS score, 95 AS projects
          UNION ALL SELECT 3, 215
          UNION ALL SELECT 1, 155
        ) q
     ON q.score = i.score
  ORDER BY i.score DESC
```

It doesn't have to be the view query in this example. But there does need to be a rowsource that the rows can be returned from.  You could, for example, have a simple table that contains those five rows, with those five score values.

This is just an example approach for the general approach.  It might be possible to modify your existing query to return the rows you want. But without seeing the query, the schema, and example data, we can't tell.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Based on the edit to the question, showing an example of the current query.

If we are guaranteed that the five values of `Score` will always appear in the `Scores` table, we could do conditional aggregation, writing a query like this:

```
 SELECT s.score
      , COUNT(IF(s.company_type = :company_type,s.project_id,NULL)) AS projects
  FROM Scores s
 GROUP BY s.score
 ORDER BY s.score DESC
```

Note that this will require a scan of all the rows, so it may not perform as well. The "trick" is the IF function, which returns a NULL value in place of project_id, when the row would have been excluded by the WHERE clause.)

If we are guaranteed that `project_id` is non-NULL, we could use a more terse  MySQL shorthand expression to achieve an equivalent result...

```
      , IFNULL(SUM(s.company_type = :company_type),0) AS projects
```

This works because MySQL returns `1` when the comparison is TRUE, and otherwisee returns 0 or NULL.

Comment: I actullly think the OP has 5 categories, fitlers one out usign a WHERE clause but wants those rows to still be returned, but with empty values. Which is a completely different intrepretation of the quesiton than yours.... However with the current information, it's kida impossible to tell who's right abotu this.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select distinct score
from (
    select distinct score from scores
) s
left outer join (
    Select Score, Count(Project_ID) cnt
    FROM Scores 
    WHERE company_type= :company_type
) x
on s.score = x.score
```

Answer (score 0):

Your posted query would not work without a `group by` statement.  However, even there, if you don't have those particular scores for that company type, it wouldn't work either.

One option is to use an `outer join`.  That would require a little more work though.

Here's another option using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select Score, sum(company_type=:company_type) 
from Scores
group by Score
```